# Как отправить httppost запрос сервлету из приложения Android?

Tags: java, android, servlet

Я работаю над небольшим клиент-серверным приложением на Android и мне нужно больше узнать про сервлеты.

У меня есть локальный сервер Tomcat, класс сервлета с методами doGet doPost. И вот главный вопрос: Может ли сервлет принимать запросы не из браузера? То есть если я зайду в браузере на этот сервак, то как и положено, будет вызван метод doGet, с этим проблем нет. 
 Но если я хочу из своего приложения ( Не браузера ) передать на сервер данные через httppost, то сможет ли сервлет их принять методом doPost? И если сможет, то можно ли будет послать ответ с данными обратно этому же клиенту? Если да, то как это все реализовать? 
 За ссылки на литературу и конкретику буду благодарен.

Comment: На все вопросы, кроме последнего, ответ ‘Да’) для реализации нужно смотреть методы обработки http вашей среды на фронтенде. Бекенду же все-равно что пришлёт запрос.

Comment: Как сервлету без разницы от чего приходит запрос, так и любому android-клиенту без разницы чему запрос отправлять. В этом смысл протоколов - в унификации взаимодействия клиента и сервера. Что касается литературы, в любом учебнике по android-разработке есть главы о работе с сетью.

Comment: Тогда можно еще вопрос: В приложении в httpost запросе я указываю url сервера и посылаю ему запрос, а вот сервлет при отправке ответа знает ли куда нужно его отправлять ( в данном случае это мой клиент )? Или дополнительно нужно что то настраивать?

Comment: @MisterGoogle, т.к. HTTP запрос суть протокол (формальное описание) поверх socket- соединения, то да, сервер будет знать кому отправлять, т.к. в момент запроса открывается и держится прямое соединение телефона и сервера по сокетам, по которым идёт непрерывный обмен данными в обе стороны. Серверу нужно просто писать в response какую-то строку - она придёт в виде ответа на андроид.

Comment: Спасибо, понял.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обращался к серверу с помощью HttpUrlConnection

```
try {
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        // For POST only - START
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
        os.write(arr.getBytes());
        os.flush();
        os.close();
        // For POST only - END
        if (con.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();
            res = response.toString();

        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", "POST NOT WORKED");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```